# ITunes' podcast image isn't shown

Tags: itunes, podcast

I created podcast rss feed - http://topdj-test.com.ua/podcast/audio-files/12/3/
And I set up "<image>" and "<itunes:image>" tags. But when I put this feed to iTunes, the picture of podcast wasn't shown in iTunes in artwork section.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes doesn't use those images: only the iTunes Store.

The images shown by iTunes are taken from the newest podcast episode. If you want iTunes to display artwork, you need to embed it in the actual media files.

Comment: ok, I see. thank you. 
It's very strange, because there is a specification about adding image to podcast (http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#image) and they say "This tag specifies the artwork for your podcast."

Answer (score -1):

Easier than anything you may have ever believed, the easiest way to get the artwork embeded in the audio files. I currently run multiple podcasts and this is the software I use is called [AudioShell](http://softpointer.com/AudioShell.htm).